# Are there any natural forms of aquatic vegetation which do not stand up in water?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

We are carrying out some experiments where we study influence of underwater vegetation on waves.  Unfortunately, the stalks of artificial 'vegetation' which we have seem to be too dense (or too stiff).  The stalks sort of stand up a bit when you put them in water but they do not stand upright and all stay partly bent over.

This might be OK depending on whether there are any natural forms of aquatic vegetation which are sort of 'bent over' due to their weight under the water and which do not 'stand upright'?  Is there any natural vegetation which does this?

Comment: Welcome to Pets. Your question doesn't quite fit here because it's not about caring for any pets. If you want, I can move it to Biology, just leave me a comment. However, I advise you to further specify the criteria you are searching for in aquatic plants. The form alone doesn't say much about its influence on waves. Most aquatic plants are quite bendy and simply flow with the water, unlike any plastic. I guess its density or strength of the stems and roots will have much more impact in a natural setting.

Comment: to make your question on topic you can change it to something like "what floating plants are best for covering the surface of my aquarium/fish tank/pool/pond"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is double posted over at https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/104383/are-there-any-natural-forms-of-aquatic-vegetation-which-do-not-stand-up-in-water

Answer (score 1):

All types of elodea  and watercress

Several types of azolla and cabomba

In addition to this several types of duckweed will float in or under the surface of the water.

All the above lives in freshwater and in addition to these there is a number of saltwater algae and seaweed that lives at the surface in the sea.